# Cannot Render in Template from Django Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i cannot render information in my template from django database.
i want to get Slider Image With Text but it's not rendering on my template.

Views.Py

```
 def slider(request):
    Slider_item = Slider.objects.get()
    context = {
    'SS' : Slider_item
    }

 return render(request, 'base.html', context=context)
```

base.html

```
 <p>{{ SS.Slider_Ttitle }} </p>
```

models.py

```
 class Slider(models.Model):
     Slider_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/sliders/', default='')
     Slider_Ttitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Slider Text')

def __str__(self):
    return self.Slider_Ttitle

class Meta:
    managed = True
    verbose_name = 'სლაიდერი'
    verbose_name_plural = 'სლაიდერები'
```

Comment: i Try Slider.objects.all() and Slider.objects.get()

Comment: With `Slider.objects.all()`, you will need to iterate over the queryset. This is a list. You normally would use a `{% for s in SS %}`

Comment: i know that... i need reason why my db is not rendering on front

Comment: Are you sure that there are Slider objects in your database?

Comment: yes :D :D i add 5 object